# How to install Totem 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gnome, software-installation, totem

I would like to know how to install Totem 3.2 in Ubuntu 12.04 because I had issues with the 3.4.3 version and 3.0.1 is too old and doesn't support some stuff that 3.2 supports. So can anyone provide me with a proper prosses that will actually install Totem 3.2 without any dependency issues?

Answer (score 0):

http://dxdown3.onlinedown.net/down/totem-3.2.1.tar.zip
You can try this.But it will download slowly.

Comment: I'm getting dep issues, can you provide other commands that will allow it to install flawlessly?

Comment: (⊙o⊙)…Maybe you need VPN for China , or download "totem-3.2.1.tar.zip" by some tools . For example , "Thunder","eMule"and so on.[Thunder should run in Windows(I don't know h)]

Comment: No, dependencies have nothing to do with downloading stuff from China. This packages depends on other packages. However I found a ppa that still supports 11.10 and has totem 3.2 so I will trick the ppa to think I'm running 11.10. Here is the ppa: https://launchpad.net/~janvitus/+archive/gnomestracciatella/+index?field.series_filter=oneiric

Comment: However after I install Totem 3.2 from that ppa Totem crashes when I launch it in 12.04 and 11.10.